# Referencing separate collection in subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two different collections: products and categories.

```
const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  category: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  description: { type: String },
  price: { type: Number, require: true },
  images: { type: [String] },
});

export const Product =
  mongoose?.models?.Product || mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);
```

```
const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
  parentCategory: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" },
  properties: [{ type: Object }],
});

export const Category =
  mongoose?.models?.Category || mongoose.model("Category", CategorySchema);
```

A category potentially has a properties field. An example properties field could be the following:

```
[
  { name: "color", values: ["gold", "silver", "red"] },
  { name: "condition", values: ["new", "used"] },
];
```

I want to be able to establish a relation between products and properties. For example, let's say our product is an iPhone 13 Pro Max. I want to be able to set the category as "cell phone" and within that category, I want to be able to account for inventory based on properties. Within the cell phone category, let's say we have color and condition as properties. I want to be able to say that there are only gold-colored iPhone 13 Pro Max's available in both new and used condition. Something like this:

```
{
  name: "iPhone 13 Pro Max",
  description: "iPhone 13 Pro Max",
  price: 1200,
  category: {
    name: "cell phones",
    properties: [
      { name: "color", values: [{ gold: true, silver: false, red: false }] },
      { name: "condition", values: [{ new: true, used: true }] },
    ],
  },
};
```

I want to be able to reference the category document from the categories collection. Right now, I am doing that but without accounting for the available properties within the category. What is the best way to this?